# How to send cmd commands from my android to my pc via adb?

Tags: android, sockets, adb

I am connected by USB and wants to send cmd commands from my android to my PC.
I tried using adb tcpip/forward but with no success.
Can anyone show me please a detailed example of tcpip connection with adb and how to send/receive messages?
Which commands I need in the client side(my PC)?
Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are using a network protocol if you are connected via USB? Can you explain further and show the steps you have taken so far?

Comment: In the end I want to write an app that control my pc by sending cmd commands. I searched in the internet for a solution and I found that it can be done by adb forward command which opens a socket between my pc and my android. If you have another way I will be glad to see

Comment: If you just want to remotely control your PC, why not use a RD Client?[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android) Most of the hard work has been done already, plus it gives you a UI to your computer

Comment: I want to learn how to do that from cmd first.

Comment: What you want is essentially what RD Clients do (i.e. open sockets, execute commands remotely). I recommend researching how RD Clients work if you want to learn/do it yourself.